# Unable to convert ajax response into jquery datatable

Tags: ajax, datatables

This is my ajax response and I want to display the output part of the response in the data table

```
   [{
    "args":{},
    "output":"[
    test{Id='1', StartTime=Fri Mar 05, EndTime=Fri Mar 05 , servers=null}, 
    test{Id='2', StartTime=Fri Mar 05, EndTime=Sat Mar 06 , servers=null}
    ]",
    "transactionContext":"test",
    "IDWithContextChain":"test"
    }]
```

My js code is :

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Table').DataTable( {
         "ajax": {
             url: "testurl",
             dataSrc:"output"
              },
        "columns": [
            { data: "Id" },
            {  data: "StartTime" },
            {  data: "EndTime" }
            ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: The string value of the `output` property in the response is a custom format and you would need to parse it with your own custom logic.  Is it possible for you to modify the server-side code to use valid JSON instead?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show how the valid json would look like?Would something like this work for the js code I've written?@David 

 [{
    "args":{},
    "output":"[
    {Id='1', StartTime=Fri Mar 05, EndTime=Fri Mar 05 , servers=null}, 
    {Id='2', StartTime=Fri Mar 05, EndTime=Sat Mar 06 , servers=null}
    ]"
    "transactionContext":"test",
    "IDWithContextChain":"test"
    }]

Comment: Ideally it wouldn't even be a JSON string, but would just be more object structure just like the object structure that contains it.  But if it needs to be a string value containing JSON then you'd want to (1) get rid of those "test" strings and (2) wrap all keys and values in double-quotes.